# My Django apps search function wont work from the tags page

Tags: python, django, django-pagination

My Site search doesn't work from tags_list.html. I think it has something to do with the pagination set up. But I can't pinpoint it. If I run a search from my tags_list.html. I get no results. But if I do it from the site index it works fine. heres my code.

my tags code
views.py:

```
def tag_list(request, slug=None):
instance = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=slug)
ins = instance.post_set.all()

query = request.GET.get("q")
if query:
    ins = ins.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query) |
            Q(content__icontains=query) |
            Q(user__first_name__icontains=query) |
            Q(user__last_name__icontains=query)
    ).distinct()
paginator = Paginator(ins, 1)
page_request_var = "tags"
page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
try:
    queryset = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    queryset = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
context = {
    "queryset": queryset,
    "paginator": paginator,
    "page_request_var": page_request_var,
}
return render(request, "posts/tag_list.html", context)
```

the pagination:

```
<div class="text-center" style="margin-bottom: 20px">

<ul class="pagination">
{% if queryset.has_previous %}
    <li><a href="?tags=1"><<</a></li>

    <li><a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.previous_page_number }}
    {% if request.GET.q %}&q={{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}">prev</a></li>
{% endif %}


{% for i in paginator.page_range %}

 <li {% if page_obj.number == i %} class="active" {% endif %}><a href="?tags={{i}}">{{i}}</a><li>

{% endfor %}


{% if queryset.has_next %}
    <li><a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.next_page_number }}
    {% if request.GET.q %}&q={{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}">next</a></li>

    <li><a href="?tags={{ queryset.paginator.num_pages }}">>></a></li>
{% endif %}
</ul>
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^tag/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', tag_list, name="tag_index"),
```

and how it looks in the url

```
http://localhost:8000/posts/tag/third-slug/?q=tesla
```

any help on how I could syntactically correct this is welcome. Thanks

Comment: please indent your code properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Everything that was ins I changed to query set and it worked

```
def tag_list(request, slug=None):
  instance = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=slug)
  ins = instance.post_set.all()
  queryset_list = Post.objects.active()
  query = request.GET.get("q")
  if query:
      queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
              Q(title__icontains=query) |
              Q(content__icontains=query) |
              Q(user__first_name__icontains=query) |
              Q(user__last_name__icontains=query)
      ).distinct()
  paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 1)
  page_request_var = "tags"
  page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
  try:
      queryset = paginator.page(page)
  except PageNotAnInteger:
      queryset = paginator.page(1)
  except EmptyPage:
      queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
  context = {
      "queryset": queryset,
      "paginator": paginator,
      "page_request_var": page_request_var,
  }
  return render(request, "posts/tag_list.html", context)
```